# Any tool to detect which dll is leaking memory?

Tags: c#, c++, memory-leaks

I have an application which includes many dlls (managed and unmanaged). The application is leaking memory when it is executing some functionalists. So I am wondering, is there anyway to detect which exactly dlls are leaking memory when the functionality is running?

I am not talking about at source code level yet, just locate the dlls that leak memory.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a memory profiler could tell you?

Comment: Thanks. Anything free?

Comment: SharpDevelop has a profiler: http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTS memory profiler is the best one out there in my opinion. It isn't free, but it does have a 14 day free trial.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a [profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288073.aspx)! If used properly you can not only find out what dll file is leaking memory, but you can find out what class/method is leaking memory. I personally like to use the [Eqatec profiler](http://www.telerik.com/analytics/eqatec-profiler).

There are several free or pay for profilers out there. And plenty of information out there to figure out which one will work best for your needs. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) is very popular and can help guide you into finding the profiler which fits you best